# How to change user provider in symfony2

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I changed to use two database in my application.

Originally,  the user authentication was implemented by using the tables of a database named 'A'.

But I would like to change to the database called B.

No problem if you want to log in new, but in the case of login Remember Me, an error that there is **no user provider** will occur.

Is there a way to avoid this problem?

an example of the code is following:

・app/config/security.yml

original

```
security:
  providers:
    main:
      entity: { class: Acme¥DemoBundle¥Entity¥User }
```

changed

```
security:
  providers:
    main:
      entity: { class: Acme¥NewDemoBundle¥Entity¥NewUser }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use two different EntityManagers?

Perhaps using the manager_name config option:

```
security:
  providers:
    main:
      entity: 
          class: Acme¥NewDemoBundle¥Entity¥NewUser 
          manager_name: entity_manager_name_for_database_B
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I use two different EntityManagers. What I want to know is how to manage user provider at rememberme cookie. Rememberme cookie has user provider information, so when I change user provider from old EM to new EM athenticate error will occur.